# How to uncheck all checkboxes belonging to the same class on change in a drop down?

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I have a function to handle change in the drop-down list as:

```
 $('#dropDownChoice').change(function () {
     debugger;
     var choice= $('#dropDownChoice option:selected').text();
     //code to display elements: the divisions that contain the checkboxes
     });


$(".chkBox").change(function () {
            debugger;
            if (this.checked) {
                $("." + this.className).not(this).prop("disabled", true);
                $(this).closest('div').find(".save").show();
                $(this).closest('div').find(':input[type="number"]').prop('disabled', false);
            }
            else {
                //opposite of that in if - block
            }

        });
```

And the check boxes (6 in number) declared as:

`<input type="checkbox" class="chkBox" >`

Now, when I check a checkbox, all the associated fields are displayed, and those for other are disabled.

My **problem** is, when the drop down changes, i.e. another option is chosen, I still get the previously selected checkbox along with the associated fields enabled, and all other check boxes invisible.

I tried using:

```
$('.chkBox').show();
$('.chkBox').removeAttr('checked');
```

And also a custom function, which I called from inside the  `$('#dropDownChoice').change(function (){}`
But this doesn't work.

```
function ResetChkBox() {
                $('.chkBox').prop('checked', false);
                $(this).closest('div').find(".save").hide();
}
```

Edit:

**HTML:**

```
<div id= "main">
    <div id="div1" style="padding-left: 20px;">
            <input type="checkbox" class="chkBox" >
            <input type="number" id="len1" disabled = "disabled"/>
            <a href='#' id="btn-save" class="glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-save save" style="display: none;" ></a>
    </div>
   //other divs each with numeric input fields and a checkbox, all checkboxes of class `chkBox`
</div>
```

**Problem Explanation:**

I need these checkboxes to be displayed when the drop-down above it changes, which I have achieved.

Now. you select one checkbox, input a value in the field and click on save, the checkboxes disappear. This too is done.

Now, you choose something else from drop-down, the checkboxes reappear, and must be unchecked. This is where in lies my problem. If you had selected, say second checkbox and saved the value, when the drop down changes, I still get the second checkbox selected and all others hidden, with their corresponding fields disabled!

Comment: Can you please share your HTML as well.

Comment: Even better if you can make it into a __working__ snippet, well working as in how far you've got.  That would make things much easier for people to help.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".chkBox").change(function () {
            debugger;
            if (this.checked) {
                 $(".chkBox").prop("checked", false);
                $(".chkBox").prop("disabled", true);
                $(this).prop("disabled",false);
                $(this).prop("checked",true);
                $(this).closest('div').find(".save").show();
                $(this).closest('div').find(':input[type="number"]').prop('disabled', false);
            }
            else {
                //opposite of that in if - block
            }

        });
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this what you need.

```js
$(".chkBox").change(function () {
            $("." + this.className).not(this).prop("disabled", $(this).is(':checked'));
            $(this).closest('div').find(':input[type="number"]').prop('disabled', !$(this).is(':checked'));
            $(".save").hide();
            $(this).closest('div').find(".save").toggle();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id= "main">
    <div id="div1" style="padding-left: 20px;">
            <input type="checkbox" class="chkBox" >
            <input type="number" id="len1" disabled = "disabled"/>
            <a href='#' id="btn-save" class="glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-save save" style="display: none;" >div1</a>
    </div>
     <div id="div2" style="padding-left: 20px;">
            <input type="checkbox" class="chkBox" >
            <input type="number" id="len2" disabled = "disabled"/>
            <a href='#' id="btn-save2" class="glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-save save" style="display: none;" >div2</a>
    </div>
     <div id="div3" style="padding-left: 20px;">
            <input type="checkbox" class="chkBox" >
            <input type="number" id="len3" disabled = "disabled"/>
            <a href='#' id="btn-save3" class="glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-save save" style="display: none;" >div3</a>
    </div>
  
</div>
```